# Proving that a certain set is compact

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I need to prove the following: Let $X$ be a normed space and $\{A_i\}$ be a sequence of compact sets in $X$ such that $$A_i \subset \epsilon_iB_X$$ for all $i$ ($B_X$ is the unit ball), and $\lim_i\epsilon_i = 0$. 
 I need to prove that the set $$A = \mathrm{cl}\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i$$  is compact.

I'm not entirely sure which direction to go. If I take a sequence that's in just the union I showed that it has a convergent subsequence, but I don't know what to do regarding a general sequence that's in the closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that $0\in A$ (find a sequence converging to it). Thus, for any open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $A$, there is some $U\in\mathcal{U}$ that contains $0$. Therefore, $U$ contains some open ball around $0$. What does that imply about $U$, in relation to the $A_i$'s? How does that help you show that you can find a finite subcover?

Comment: That it contains an infinite number of them?

Comment: Yes, but not *just* infinitely many; all but finitely many!

Comment: Then the union of the remaining A_i's is compact because there is a finite amount? Then we're done aren't we?

Comment: Yup, that's right!

Comment: I just realized that this yields a finite subcover of the union of the A_i's, and not the closure. How can cover the closure too?

Answer (score 1):

Take a sequence $x_n\in\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$. We have two cases:

Case 1: There is some $i$ such that $x_n\notin \epsilon_i B_X$, for $n$ large enough.

In this case we have that $x_n$ is contained in a finite union of the $A_i$'s, and because this finite union is compact, you can extract a convergent subsequence.

Case 2: For each $i$, we can find a $x_{n_{i}}$ (depending on $i$) such that $x_{n_{i}}\in\epsilon_i B_X$

In this case, because $\epsilon_i\rightarrow 0$, we can conclude that $x_{n_{i}}\rightarrow 0$

From cases 1 and 2, we have that $\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ is relatively compact.

Comment: I did exactly that, but we need to take a sequence in the closure not just the union right? Not sure what relatively compact means.

Comment: Relatively compact is a synonym for precompact; these terms mean that the closure of the set is compact.

Comment: It is lile @ZevChonoles said. If you did it, then you have proved that every sequence has a subsequence, converging for some point, but by definition this point is in the closure of the set.

Comment: As far as I can see, what you proved is that every sequence in the union has a convergent subsequence to an element in the closure of the union. But what about sequences that aren't necessarily in the union, but rather in the closure of the union? How can we know they too have convergent subsequences?

Comment: Take a sequence $x_n$ in the boundary of $\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$. By definition of boundary, for each $n$, you can find $y_n$ in $\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$, such that $\|x_n-y_n\|<\frac{1}{n}$. Take a subsequence of $y_n$ still denoted by $y_n$ that converges for some $y$. Can you conclude from here?

Comment: Not really :S. I followed until the third line. You say "Take a subsequence y_n...that converges for some y", but isn't the existence of such a thing what we need to prove?

Comment: Note that $y_n$ is in $\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$, and we alread proved this property for this set. Also remeber that $\overline {\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i}=\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\cup \partial (\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i)$.

Comment: I see, then the subsequence of x_n converges to the same thing as the subsequence of y_n, which is in the closure and we're done.

Comment: Yes that's the idea.